# Execute huge network on laptop for prediction

Tags: deep-learning, operating-system

I have trained a huge neural network (capsule network with bigger dimensions, more classes etc) on Google cloud. The network needs around 400 GB RAM and 4 GPUs to train it without crashing. Theoretically what I heard is that neural networks can execute on a normal PC *for predictions*. But given that it needed so much resources to train, is it still possible to download the tensorflow checkpoint and run the network on my laptop to **make predictions**?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, reducing the batch size caused the network to train even in high dimension capsules.
In fact, TensorFlow will get copies of the network for each batch for parallelizing and a big batch size may not be stored in GPU memory.